# No puede pasar una variable a una funcion en python. GUI Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una interfaz gráfica usando Tkinter en python. Me están ocurriendo cosas que no consigo resolver, a ver si podeis ayudarme por favor...

Tengo esta función en la que creo una ventana con un botón y un Entry.

```
def GUIdatos():
    
    window = Tk()
    numTareas= IntVar()
    
#Frames
    
    mainframe=Frame(window)
    mainframe.grid()
    mainframe.config(bg="lightblue")
    
    tareaLabel=Label(mainframe,text="Número de tareas")
    tareaLabel.grid(column=0,row=0, padx=5,pady=10)
    
    numTareas.set("")
       entryTareas=Entry(mainframe,textvariable=numTareas,width=5,justify="center")
    entryTareas.grid(column=1,row=0,ipadx=5,ipady=5, padx=5,pady=10)
    
    #BOTONES
    
    tareaButtom=ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Aplicar",command= lambda: creaFrameTareas( numTareas,window))
    tareaButtom.grid(column=2,row=0,ipadx=5,ipady=5, padx=10,pady=10)

    window.mainloop()
```

Hasta aquí todo bien en principio.Cuando pulso el botón llamo a otra función (creaFrameTareas) que captura el valor del entry guardado en la variable "numTareas" y dibuja otros widgets en "window" (por eso también se lo paso) . Aquí viene el problema, python me dice que no está definida la variable numTareas ¿ Por qué?!! Y preveo que tendré también problemas con "window" por todas las cosas que he estado probando.

Esto es parte de la funcion creaFrameTareas:

```
def  creaFrameTareas(numTareas,window):     
    array_iter=[]
    array_numEquipos=[]
    
    options_numequipos=["1",
             "2",
             "3",
             "4",
             "5"]
    
    num_tareas=numTareas.get()
    for tarea in range(1,num_tareas+1):
        
        locals()["intIter" + str(tarea)] = IntVar()
        
        locals()["FrameTarea" + str(tarea)] = Frame(window
```

Añadir a lo ya escrito que esos problemas me dan cuando ejecuto la función GUIdatos() directamente. El código en realidad tiene otra función que crea una primera ventana para logearse y una vez te logueas llama a la función GUIdatos(). La llamada la hace correctamente, y al ejecutarse GUIdatos se muestra una nueva ventana con el campo Entry y un botón, como debe ser. Cuando introduzco un valor en el campo Entry y le doy al botón (se ejecuta entonces la función creaFrameTareas) me da un error que es el siguiente:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\XXX\anaconda3\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 545, in
> get
> return self._tk.getint(value)
> _tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got ""
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\XXX\anaconda3\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1892, in
> **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\XXX\ProyectosPython\Trabajo_de_
> curso_DiseñoII\GUI_inputData.py", line 147, in 
> tareaButtom=ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Aplicar",command= lambda: creaFrameTareas( numTareas,window))   File
> "C:\Users\XXX\ProyectosPython\Trabajo_de_
> curso_DiseñoII\GUI_inputData.py", line 28, in creaFrameTareas
> print(numTareas.get())   File "C:\Users\XXX\anaconda3\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 547, in get
> return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
> _tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

Parece ser que no lee nada del widget Entry, pero si estoy escribiendo en el !!

Toda ayuda es bienvenida.

Gracias!!

Decir que el código me funcionaba perfectamente. Todos los problemas han empezado cuando lo he metido en funciones.

Comment: nop, el error que muestras es distinto al que describes. En el error se te dice que en el entry se espera un valor entero pero recibe `""` (cadena vacía). Esto se ocasiona por el `set` que haces: `numTareas.set("")`. No sé mucho de tkinter por lo cual no digo como puedes solucionarlo.

Comment: Sí, eso entiendo yo también de ese error, pero estoy escribiendo en el campo! Cuando ejecuto la funcion GUIdatos directamente es cuando me da el primer error descrito, y quizas esten relacionados de alguna forma...

Comment: repito, no sé mucho de tkinter y no sé como resolver este problema

Comment: probaste haciendo el `numTareas.get()` en la función lambda ? algo así: `lambda: creaFrameTareas( numTareas.get(),window))
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Nota*: Esta respuesta está basada en suposiciones, lo cual la puede hacer incorrecta. Si la respuesta no resolvió tu duda, por favor dimelo y la borraré.

#### Como llegué a estas conclusiones

Al principio, estaba por decirte que no había logrado replicar el problema. Pero luego leí con atención tu pregunta, y mencionas que antes de la ventana mostrada en el código, abres una de login.

Entonces, supuse que tanto la ventana anterior como la nueva la inicializas creando una instancia de Tk.

Por lo que pude replicar tu problema con el siguiente código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def  creaFrameTareas(numTareas,window):     
    array_iter=[]
    array_numEquipos=[]
    
    options_numequipos=["1",
             "2",
             "3",
             "4",
             "5"]
    
    num_tareas=numTareas.get()
    for tarea in range(1,num_tareas+1):
        
        locals()["intIter" + str(tarea)] = IntVar()
        
        locals()["FrameTarea" + str(tarea)] = Frame(window)

def GUIdatos():
    
    window = Tk()
    numTareas= IntVar()
    
    #Frames
    
    mainframe=Frame(window)
    mainframe.grid()
    mainframe.config(bg="lightblue")
    
    tareaLabel=Label(mainframe,text="Número de tareas")
    tareaLabel.grid(column=0,row=0, padx=5,pady=10)
    
    numTareas.set("")
    entryTareas=Entry(mainframe,textvariable=numTareas,width=5,justify="center")
    entryTareas.grid(column=1,row=0,ipadx=5,ipady=5, padx=5,pady=10)
    
    #BOTONES
    
    tareaButtom=ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Aplicar",command= lambda: creaFrameTareas( numTareas,window))
    tareaButtom.grid(column=2,row=0,ipadx=5,ipady=5, padx=10,pady=10)

    window.mainloop()

Tk()
GUIdatos()
```

Si destruyo la primera instancia de Tk, el error no ocurre.

No tengo idea de que razón interna puede haber, pero si se la solución.

Usar varias instancias de Tk al mismo tiempo [es algo no recomendado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged).

#### Solución 1: Destruye la ventana de login.

Antes de iniciar la nueva ventana, destruye la de login con `laventana.destroy()`. Además, una vez que el usuario esté logueado, no necesitarás esa ventana, verdad?

#### Solución 2: Toplevels

Si por alguna razón deseas conservar la ventana de login, en lugar de crear la ventana con el comando Tk, creala con `Toplevel(ventana_padre)`. Los toplevels tienen unas cuantas ventajas:

- No ocurren estos errores extraños
- Si la ventana se cierra, todos sus toplevels también.
- Los toplevels funcionan casi igual a una ventana de Tk.

En esta solución, el unico cambio a hacer sería cambiar esta linea:

```
window = Tk()
```

por

```
window = Toplevel()
```

#### bonus

A diferencia del diccionario devuelto por la función globals(), modificar el diccionario devuelto por locals() NO creará ni borrará variables locales. En tu caso particular te recomendaría usar diccionarios.

```
intIter = {}
FrameTarea = {}

num_tareas=numTareas.get()

for tarea in range(1,num_tareas+1):
    intIter[tarea] = IntVar()
    FrameTarea[tarea] = Frame(window)

#Obtengo el valor que contiene el intvar de la tarea 1
print(intIter[1].get())
#Obtengo frame de la tarea 1
print(FrameTarea[1])
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Dante. Un par de horas después de publicar la pregunta, después de probar 1000 cosas, probé a destruir la ventana antigua y solucionó el problema, así que has llegado a la conclusión correcta y mucho antes que yo!! jaja. También reinicié Spyder y quizás también tenga algo que ver. No se si os ha ocurrido alguna vez pero hace cosas raras. Por ejemplo, en un script tengo una funcion , la llamo desde la consola de Spyder y me dice que no está definida... No me lo explico.