# Por qué imprime el mismo valor de 2 radiobutton?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de imprimir el valor de un 2 radiobutton (`femenino(valor=1)` y `masculino(valor=2)`), para lo cual utilizo una variable de control, `Invar()`, para guardar el valor en el momento de seleccionar uno de ellos, pero al seleccionar cualquiera de los dos me imprime siempre el mismo valor (`0`). Eh revisado el código de arriba a abajo y no veo el error, alguien me podría ayudar.

```py
from tkinter import *

class CrearC(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master,width=700,height=500)
        self.Var = IntVar()
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.CrearWidget()

    def verradio(self):
        print(self.Var.get())

    def CrearWidget(self):
        frame10 = Frame(self, width=700, height=430)
        frame10.place(x=0, y=70)

        Radiobutton(frame10, text="Masculino", variable=self.Var, value=1).place(x=325, y=290)
        Radiobutton(frame10, text="Femenino", variable=self.Var, value=2).place(x=460, y=290)


        Button(frame10, text="Crear cuenta", width=50, height=3, bg="#304739", command=self.verradio).place(x=140, y=340)
```

Comment: El código que publicas no tiene ningún error, hace lo que debería.

Comment: Entonces cual puede ser el problema , un error de PyCharm? por que no entiendo por que me sigue dando 0

Comment: Eso es raro. Es posible que cuando creaste el código que publicaste lo hayas solucionado accidentalmente? Tal vez la versión de Python, de TCL, de Tkinter...?

Comment: Bueno seguiré intentando. Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: De nada! Probaste el código de la pregunta para ver si te anda bien?

Comment: perdon la ignorancia ,pero cual es el codigo de la pregunta?

Comment: No hay problema. Me refiero al código que publicaste.

Comment: Hola como estas, considerando que me dijiste que el codigo esta bien, le di apertura directa desde el main y efectivamente funciona. pero entre el main y el codigo de la pregunta hay otra ventana que es la que esta causando el problema, todavia no lo descubri pero estoy desglosando y probando uno por uno. el punto es que ya se donde esta el problema que es un avance.

Comment: Estás abriendo dos o más ventanas usando Tk?

Comment: si. el problema es eso?

Comment: Parece que sí. Pues he creado dos ventanas con Tk, implementado tu código en la segunda ventana y ahí sí me ocurre el error que mencionas. Hace tiempo alguien también tuvo un problema por hacer lo mismo, te recomiendo leer la respuesta que le dejé: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/509131/158880

Comment: ok. te agradezco por tus respuestas

Comment: excelente. es la solución q buscaba. ademas aprendí algo nuevo. te agradezco la paciencia y el tiempo. el problema era q abría múltiples ventanas tk.

Comment: De nada ric do :D