# Error de imagen en TkInter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

mi problema es este, estoy haciendo el programa que es una especie de launcher de unos juegos y cuando con la ventana presiono el boton para que me mande al launcher y:

1. no se elimino con root.destroy()
2. en el launcher no aparece mi imagen
   Archivo _ _ main _ _.py

```py
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
import codes
def sks(arguments):
    import sk
    exec("sk")
    root.destroy()
def __initapp__():
    root=Tk()
    root.title("SaDro Launcher")
    root.geometry("800x600")
    principal=Button(root,text="Pagina Principal",bg="red")
    principal.place(x=0,y=0)
    about=Button(root,text="Sobre nosotros")
    about.place(x=94,y=0)
    fontvar=("TkFixedFont",24)
    fontvarnormal=("TkFixedFont",10)
    fontvarsmall=("TkFixedFont", 7)
    playto=Label(root,text="Jugar a",font=fontvar)
    playto.place(x=0,y=26)
    StrikerKilleImage=PhotoImage(file="H:/BIND.D/APPS/ENPROCESO/GAME_PETER/APP/125x125.png")
    StrikerKilleImageLabel=Label(root,image=StrikerKilleImage)
    StrikerKilleImageLabel.place(x=0,y=25)
    Strikerkillshot=Label(root,text="S͟t͟ʀ͟ɩ͟ĸ͟ɘ͟ʀ͟K͟ɩ͟ɭ͟ɭ͟s͟ʜ͟o͟t͟™",font=fontvarnormal,fg="blue")
    Strikerkillshot.bind("<Button-1>",sks)#Si se toca el label Strikerkillshot, se ejecuta sks()
    Strikerkillshot.place(x=0,y=172)
    Strikerkillshotimagetext=Label(root,text="Imagen de StʀɩĸɘʀKɩɭɭsʜot™",font=fontvarsmall)
    Strikerkillshotimagetext.place(x=0,y=149)
    root.mainloop()
def submit():
    serialcode=serial.get()
    if serialcode in codes.KeyCodes:
        root.destroy()
        __initapp__()
root=Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
serial=Entry(root)
serial.place(x=90,y=30)
submitb=Button(root,text="Enviar",command=submit)
submitb.place(x=90,y=50)
root.mainloop()
```

Archivo sk.py

```py
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title("StrikerKillerShot")
root.config(bg="white")
root.geometry("800x600")
root.resizable(0,0)
SksLabel=Label(root,text="StrikerKillerShot",bg="white",font=("TkFixedFont",24))
SksLabel.place(x=285,y=260)
SksLaunch=Button(root,text="Jugar",width=35,height=2,bg="white",font=("TkFixedFont"))
SksLaunch.place(x=280,y=300)
SksImage=PhotoImage(file="H:/bind.d/apps/enproceso/game_peter/app/250x250.png")#Esta imagen no aparece
SksImageLabel=Label(root,image=SksImage)#Esta imagen no aparece
SksImageLabel.place(x=280,y=0)
root.mainloop()
```

por favor, Que sucede en mi programa
En el visual studio code no aparecen errores y el directorio de la imagen esta escrito correctamente

Comment: Que es el modulo codes? Lo creaste vos? Lo descargaste?

Comment: El modulo codes es otro script que son 1000 claves de productos, lo unico que es es un script que dice "KeyCodes=["codigos","de","producto"]" (Pero solo son codigos con formato 4*5), como veras en el script main.py cree un boton submit y todo para la clave de producto

Comment: Los codigos de producto son cadenas? Es decir, están entre comillas?

Comment: Si, al inicio del programa este pregunta el serial y comprueba si existe en la variable PostData: No son numeros, son como "UTCS-SDSE-SADS-WDWE-DSAS"

Comment: Entonces, si entiendo bien el primer problema, apretás el botón submit y no destruye la ventana anterior. Y el segundo error es que en lugar de las imágenes aparece un cuadrado del mismo color que la ventana. Estoy en lo correcto? Por que si estoy en lo correcto entiendo bien el segundo problema pero no el primero.

Comment: en el boton submit, comprueba si el entry coincide con una de las 1000 claves y si coincide "root.destroy()" y "__initapp__()" las imagenes no son blancas, son iconos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135455/discussion-between-fourseven-and-dante-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Causa de ambos errores

Ya encontré lo que está pasando. Según un video que me mandaste, de hecho SI aparece un error en el Visual Studio Code. Ese error está haciendo que la función deje de ejecutarse, por lo que no llega a ejecutar el `root.destroy()`.

Como el error ocurre a la hora de cargar la imagen, tampoco aparece dicha imagen (ni lo que se crea después).

Aquí dejo una transcripción de la parte final del error, el cual ocurre cuando se importa el módulo sk.

```
image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

#### Causa del error de consola

Lo que pasa es que estás abriendo dos ventanas usando `Tk()`. Esto [no es recomendado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged) ya que produce este tipo de errores extraños.
No se la causa con seguridad.

Por favor lee esta respuesta que di a otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/509131/158880

#### Solución

En este caso particular, resaltaré una parte de esa respuesta (enfasis agregado especificamente para esta respuesta)

> Solución 1
>
> Destruye la ventana de login. **Antes** de iniciar la nueva
> ventana, destruye la de login con laventana.destroy(). Además, una vez
> que el usuario esté logueado, no necesitarás esa ventana, verdad?

Como podrás notar, uso la palabra "antes". En cambio lo que vos hacés es cerrarla despues.

Por lo tanto, la solución es tan simple como cambiar el orden de las instrucciones a ejecutar:

Por cierto, no necesitas el exec para que se ejecute el código del modulo sk.

```
def sks(arguments):
    root.destroy()
    import sk
```

Pero esto va a traer otro problema. El programa **no** va a intentar cerrar la ventana creada en `__initapp__`, si no que va a intentar cerrar la primera ventana que creaste.

¿Por que? Por que la primera ventana la creas en el ambito global, mientras la segunda ventana la creas en el ambito local de una función aparte.  Cuando Python intente buscar la variable root, va a buscar primero dentro de la función sks, luego la función dentro de la que está sks, y así hasta llegar al ambito global. En este caso particular, solo buscará dentro de sks y en el ambito global. Si quieres entender mejor este punto, te recomiendo leer: https://www.codigopiton.com/variables-locales-y-globales-en-python

#### Ejemplo de un intento de acceder a una variable local de otra función.

```
def func1():
    a = 1
    print(b)

def func2():
    b = 2

b = "Esta variable es global"

func1()
```

Esto produce:

```
Esta variable es global
```

Lo que sí puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
def func2():
    b = 2

    def func1():
        a = 1
        print(b)

    func1()

b = "Esta variable es global"

func2()
```

Que imprime:

```
2
```

En este caso, se logró acceder a la variable no local `b`. Pero como podrás notar, solo funciona con funciones anidadas.

#### Solución definitiva

Entonces, por que no hacemos de sks una función anidada?

El código de `__main__` quedaría así:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
import codes

def __initapp__():
    def sks(arguments):
        root.destroy()
        import sk

    root=Tk()
    root.title("SaDro Launcher")
    root.geometry("800x600")
    principal=Button(root,text="Pagina Principal",bg="red")
    principal.place(x=0,y=0)
    about=Button(root,text="Sobre nosotros")
    about.place(x=94,y=0)
    fontvar=("TkFixedFont",24)
    fontvarnormal=("TkFixedFont",10)
    fontvarsmall=("TkFixedFont", 7)
    playto=Label(root,text="Jugar a",font=fontvar)
    playto.place(x=0,y=26)
    StrikerKilleImage=PhotoImage(file="H:/BIND.D/APPS/ENPROCESO/GAME_PETER/APP/125x125.png")
    StrikerKilleImageLabel=Label(root,image=StrikerKilleImage)
    StrikerKilleImageLabel.place(x=0,y=25)
    Strikerkillshot=Label(root,text="S͟t͟ʀ͟ɩ͟ĸ͟ɘ͟ʀ͟K͟ɩ͟ɭ͟ɭ͟s͟ʜ͟o͟t͟™",font=fontvarnormal,fg="blue")
    Strikerkillshot.bind("<Button-1>",sks)#Si se toca el label Strikerkillshot, se ejecuta sks()
    Strikerkillshot.place(x=0,y=172)
    Strikerkillshotimagetext=Label(root,text="Imagen de StʀɩĸɘʀKɩɭɭsʜot™",font=fontvarsmall)
    Strikerkillshotimagetext.place(x=0,y=149)
    root.mainloop()
def submit():
    serialcode=serial.get()
    if serialcode in codes.KeyCodes:
        root.destroy()
        __initapp__()
root=Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
serial=Entry(root)
serial.place(x=90,y=30)
submitb=Button(root,text="Enviar",command=submit)
submitb.place(x=90,y=50)
root.mainloop()
```

#### Bonus

Te recomiendo evitar el uso de nombres rodeados con `__` a menos de que sea absolutamente necesario. Estos nombres suelen ser usados por Python internamente y podrías reemplazar algo interno sin querer.